# What is solution for center alignment in html?

Tags: html, alignment, margin

I have an html page :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
All Time Set Window
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" style="width:1000px; height:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <div style="width:100%; height:20%; background-color:#F8E0E0; float:top;">
        <div align="center">This is Header</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; height:60%; background-color:#F5F6CE;">
        <div align="center" style="width:70%; background-color:#E3F6CE; float:left;">This is Left Frame</div>
        <div align="center" style="width:30%; background-color:#E0E0F8; float:right;">This is Right Frame</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; height:20%; float:bottom; background-color:#F8E0E0;">
        <div align="center">This is Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used Margin-left & Margin-right to auto for taking div to center. This is working in Mozilla & not in Explorer. What is solution for the same.

Comment: margin:auto; is not working in Explorer & only working in Mozilla. That is what the problem is.

Comment: But, once again I say that the question has been of not working with IE8+. What is solution for same. I have tried
1) margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
2) margin:auto;
3) margin: 0px auto;
Still......

Comment: You'll get on a lot better if you're not forcing IE into quirks mode. Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the start of your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution (according to the spec) is the one you have.  You should set both margins to auto to center the block.

But as usual, explorer does not play by the rules.  To make it center a block you have to set `text-align` of the parent element to `center`.  Since you probably don't want all the text in your element itself to be centered as well, you'll have to negate the behaviour again by setting `text-align` to `left` on that one.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>All Time Set Window</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <div align="center" style="width:1000px; height:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:left">
        <div style="width:100%; height:20%; background-color:#F8E0E0; float:top;">
          <div align="center">This is Header</div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%; height:60%; background-color:#F5F6CE;">
          <div align="center" style="width:70%; background-color:#E3F6CE; float:left;">This is Left Frame</div>
          <div align="center" style="width:30%; background-color:#E0E0F8; float:right;">This is Right Frame</div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%; height:20%; float:bottom; background-color:#F8E0E0;">
          <div align="center">This is Footer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add auto to your margin

```
<div style="margin:10px auto;width:100px;">stuff</div>
```

This div will be centered because of the `auto` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
margin:0px auto;
```

an you'd have to specify a width

Answer (score 0):

```
#yourdiv
{
 position:absolute;
 left: 50%; 
 width: 700px;
 margin-left: -350px;
 top: 50%;
 height: 400px;
 margin-top: -200px;
}
```

The properties `left`, `width` and `margin-left` are for horizontal alignment, and the `top`, `height` and `margin-top` for the vertical one. If you put all of them, you will have a div perfectly centered in your page.

Answer (score 0):

For internet exxplorer you can set a text-align center on your body, and on your div text-align: left.

That should do the trick ;-)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you looking for?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <center>
        --- olalala place your content here ---
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```